# Where to download microsoft "Visual C++: Samples Included in Visual C++"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Microsoft website listed the Visual C++ samples at [Visual C++: Samples Included in Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1370z17c.aspx), however, I could not find the download page.

Visual Studio menu, Help, Samples, does come out a dialog showing that I can download samples from online, but it seems not include the projects in the listing page above, for example, I tried to search "[DLLScreenCap Sample: Demonstrates a Regular DLL That Statically or Dynamically Links to MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a51wcfx.aspx)" but to no avail.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Where could one find such samples?

Comment: Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I'm using VS 2013 Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find every sample in the [Visual Studio Developer Center](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio).

Note that most of the examples on your page are deprecated, i.e. they are not available for download any more. You would have to find other samples that fit your needs.